# What are the differences between AuxilliarySenorDesigner (driver) vs CustomSensorDesigner?

Tags: sensors, sensormanager, sensor-fusion

I noticed two blocks in InvenSense SensorStudio  which appear to be very similar.  hey are AuxillarySensorDesign (driver) and CustomSensorDesigner block.  What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**AuxilliarySenorDesigner**

- Connect to device block (and not to sensor block)
- Does not support emulation
- Must be used to create driver sensors that get data from hardware (I2C)

**CustomSensorDesigner**

- Connect to one or several sensors block
- Support emulation
- Should be used to create virtual sensors that gets data from other sensors in the system and apply some algorithm

**CustomSensor**

- Connect to device block
- Used to retrieve sensor data from custom sensors from the device (after flashing a firmware)

Refer to "3.6. DESIGN YOUR SENSOR ALGORITHM", "3.7. SENSOR FRAMEWORK EXPLAINED" and "3.8. DESIGN YOUR SENSOR DRIVER" of 001 - SensorStudio User Documentation.pdf available with your SensorStudio installation